# Ignoring metatable in Lua?

Tags: lua, draw, metatable

I'm working on a Lua menu, and I got Menu class which creates instances like this:

```
function Menu:new(label, action, open)
    local inst = {
        parent = self,
        label = label,
        action = action,
        open = open or self.defaultOpenState,
        current = false
    }
    setmetatable( inst, { __index = self } )
    if self.subMenus then
        table.insert( self.subMenus, inst )
    else
        self.subMenus = { inst }
    end
    return inst
end
```

That's not all the code obviously for the menu, but that's enough to explain my problem. The menu is working just fine, how ever, printing it isn't. Problem is, I'm using recursive method to print out all the submenus, but it keeps on printing the very first menu over and over again. I know what causes it, but not sure how to fix it. Here's the code:

```
function Menu:draw(indent)
    local indent = indent or 0
    if self.label then
        if self.current then
            print( string.rep( "    ", indent ) .. self:getDirectoryMark() .. "<" .. self.label .. ">" )
        else
            print( string.rep( "    ", indent ) .. self:getDirectoryMark() .. " " .. self.label )
        end
    end
    if self.subMenus and self.open then
        for k, v in ipairs( self.subMenus ) do
            v:draw( indent + 1 )
        end
    end
end
```

And the problem is (I suppose it is, correct me if I'm wrong?), that on line 10 `if self.subMenus ...` it is always true. There's always a subMenu, even if there wasn't, since the menu (self) doesn't find a submenu, it checks for it's metatable, which has subMenu, and then on line 11, it does the for loop for it's metatables submenus. Which means, it'll draw itself again. And again. And again. So is there a way to bypass a metatable, in just one place? Or am I even right, is the repeated printing caused by that?

Comment: Found out there's a function called `rawget(table, index)`, which does exactly what I want. Was pretty easy, just couldn't find any information from google with keywords "ignore metatable lua" ... :"/

Comment: It would be great if you could answer this question yourself and mark it answered, so that other readers searching for "Lua ignore metatable" end up here with a visible answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`rawget(table, index)`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-rawget).